# Why is $\Pr(Y \le a) = \Pr(Y \le a , X \le a + \epsilon) + \Pr(Y \le a , X > a + \epsilon)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables, furthermore, let $a$ be a real number and $\epsilon > 0$. Then we can say that:

$$\Pr(Y \le a) = \Pr(Y \le a , X \le a + \epsilon) + \Pr(Y \le a , X > a + \epsilon).$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: For any events $A,B$, we have $\Omega=A\sqcup A^c$ and $B=B\cap\Omega=(B\cap A)\sqcup(B\cap A^c)$. Use this with $B:=\{Y\le a\}$ and $A:=\{X\le a+\epsilon\}$.

Comment: It's the law of total probability: $P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A^c)$.

Comment: What does $:=$ mean?